# Failed to find font DejaVu Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=10.0, and fallback to the default font disabled

Tags: python

findfont: Generic family 'sans-serif' not found because none of the following families were found: DejaVu Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, Computer Modern Sans Serif, Lucida Grande, Verdana, Geneva, Lucid, Arial, Helvetica, Avant Garde, sans-serif

1. findfont: Font family ['DejaVu Sans'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
2. Error in callback <function _draw_all_if_interactive at 0x10f546ca0> (for post_execute):

Python 3.11.4 (main, Jul  5 2023, 08:54:11) [Clang 14.0.6 ]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 8.12.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('/Users/kristenhoskins/Desktop/Python Problem/Problem 2.py', wdir='/Users/kristenhoskins/Desktop/Python Problem')
findfont: Generic family 'sans-serif' not found because none of the following families were found: DejaVu Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, Computer Modern Sans Serif, Lucida Grande, Verdana, Geneva, Lucid, Arial, Helvetica, Avant Garde, sans-serif
findfont: Font family ['DejaVu Sans'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
Traceback (most recent call last):

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:340 in **call**
return printer(obj)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py:152 in print_figure
fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:2158 in print_figure
self.figure.draw(renderer)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:95 in draw_wrapper
result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:72 in draw_wrapper
return draw(artist, renderer)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py:3154 in draw
mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py:132 in _draw_list_compositing_images
a.draw(renderer)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:72 in draw_wrapper
return draw(artist, renderer)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:3034 in draw
self._update_title_position(renderer)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:2978 in _update_title_position
ax.yaxis.get_tightbbox(renderer)  # update offsetText

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1336 in get_tightbbox
self._update_label_position(renderer)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:2609 in _update_label_position
bboxes, bboxes2 = self._get_tick_boxes_siblings(renderer=renderer)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:2161 in _get_tick_boxes_siblings
tlb, tlb2 = axis._get_ticklabel_bboxes(ticks_to_draw, renderer)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1315 in _get_ticklabel_bboxes
return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1315 in 
return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py:956 in get_window_extent
bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py:373 in _get_layout
_, lp_h, lp_d = _get_text_metrics_with_cache(

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py:69 in _get_text_metrics_with_cache
return _get_text_metrics_with_cache_impl(

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py:77 in _get_text_metrics_with_cache_impl
return renderer_ref().get_text_width_height_descent(text, fontprop, ismath)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:220 in get_text_width_height_descent
font = self._prepare_font(prop)

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:254 in _prepare_font
font = get_font(_fontManager._find_fonts_by_props(font_prop))

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1381 in _find_fonts_by_props
self.findfont(

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1292 in findfont
ret = self._findfont_cached(

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1443 in _findfont_cached
return self.findfont(default_prop, fontext, directory,

File ~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1296 in findfont
raise ret.klass(ret.message)

ValueError: Failed to find font DejaVu Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=10.0, and fallback to the default font was disabled

I am having a font issue that is disabled, and nothing will work if I try to import matplot. The 3rd pane will never pull any graphs for me.